# Functions to Polymorphic data types

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, gadt, existential-type

data `Foo a` is defined like:

```
data Foo a where
  Foo :: (Typeable a, Show a) => a -> Foo a
  -- perhaps more constructors

instance Show a => Show (Foo a) where
  show (Foo a) = show a
```

with some instances:

```
fiveFoo :: Foo Int
fiveFoo = Foo 5

falseFoo :: Foo Bool
falseFoo = Foo False
```

How can I define any function from `b -> Foo a`, for example:

```
getFoo :: (Show a, Typeable a) => String -> Foo a
getFoo "five" = fiveFoo
getFoo "false" = falseFoo
```

Here `getFoo` does not type check with `Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Bool’`.

The only thing that I am interested in here is for `a` to be of class `Show`so I can use `getFoo` like:

```
main = getLine >>= (print . getFoo)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you want to omit the type parameter from Foo.

```
data Foo where
  Foo :: (Typeable a, Show a) => a -> Foo

instance Show Foo where
  show (Foo a) = show a

fiveFoo :: Foo
fiveFoo = Foo (5 :: Int) -- (Foo 5) doesn't work because of ambiguity

falseFoo :: Foo
falseFoo = Foo False

getFoo :: String -> Foo
getFoo "five" = fiveFoo
getFoo "false" = falseFoo

print $ getFoo "five" -- prints '5'
print $ getFoo "false" -- prints 'False'
```

Comment: I like this, but I wonder if the OP really needs it -- it's easy to fall in the [existential antipattern](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/). Only the OP knows, though.

Comment: @chi yes this is existential thingy but I don't think it's so much an antipattern. I know I'm an a minority here.

Comment: Did we made `Foo` a union type here? Is this equivalent to `data Foo = IFoo Int | BFoo Bool`?

Comment: @n.m. Well, I also think Luke Palmer is a bit too extreme in its blog post. Still, I think using e.g. a list of Show-ables instead of a list of strings is a pointless overcomplication. In my view the type `Foo` above is valuable, but only because of the `Typeable` constraint, which allows one to `cast` later on and recover the type. Otherwise, `Foo` is isomorphic to a string (or, at most, to a string-builder function as in `shows`) so using existentials looks a bit overkill.

Comment: @homam No it's not equivalent. `Foo` can also contain strings, pairs of ints, lists of lists of ints, etc. It can wrap anything which is showable (and typeable).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [existential types](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type) to make a data type hide and "carry" a type class like `Show` around.

Note that using existential types like this is considered to be an [anti-pattern](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) in Haskell, and you probably want to consider carefully whether you really want to do this: being more explicit about your types is usually simpler, better, and less prone to bugs.

However, that being said, if you really want to do this, here is how you would use existential types with your example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

-- This Foo can only be constructed with instances of Show as its argument.
data Foo = forall a. Show a => Foo a

-- Note that there is no "Show a => ..." context here:
-- Foo itself already carries that constraint around with it.
instance Show Foo where
  show (Foo a) = show a


getFoo :: String -> Foo
getFoo "five" = Foo 5
getFoo "false" = Foo False

main = print . getFoo =<< getLine
```

Demonstration:

```
ghci> main
five
5
ghci> main
false
False
```

Comment: `data Foo a` --- `a` is redundant here, the "inner" `a` inside `forall` is a different variable!

Comment: also, the GADT solution is almost exactly the same as the existential solution (and I have used a GADT only because OP used one) Don't GADTs subsume existential types?

Answer (score 2):

```
getFoo :: (Show a, Typeable a) => String -> Foo a
getFoo "five" = fiveFoo
getFoo "false" = falseFoo
```

If `fiveFoo :: Foo Int` and `falseFoo :: Foo Bool`, you're essentially asking for `getFoo` to return a different type depending on what value you feed it at run-time. You can't do that. In Haskell, all types must be known at *compile-time*.

If all you want to be able to do is convert the thing to a string, why not just store it as a string in the first place? I'm guessing the answer is that this is actually a simplification of the real problem you're trying to solve...(?)

Comment: Well you're right. I tried to boil down my problem to its simplest. I want to create a series of `Nodes a b` (like a Category) so that each Node processes an input from user and continue with either another `Node b a'` or with the final result `b`.

Comment: This is closer to my real problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147517/functions-of-gadts