# Functions of GADTs

Tags: haskell, gadt

It's a followup question of [Functions to Polymorphic data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143379/functions-to-polymorphic-data-types)

Data type `Question` models a question/answer with a `Message` (the text of the question) and a function (`String -> a`) that maps user's input to the result of the question:

```
data Question where
  Simple :: (Typeable a, Show a) => Message -> (String -> a) -> Question
```

This CLI program should first gets the name of the `Question`, find an instance using `getQuestion` function and then run the `Question` and print out the result.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Data.Typeable

type Message = String

data Question where
  Simple :: (Typeable a, Show a) => Message -> (String -> a) -> Question
  -- more constructors

yourName :: Question
yourName = Simple "Your name?" id

yourWeight :: Question
yourWeight = Simple "What is your weight?" (read :: String -> Int)

getQuestion :: String -> Question
getQuestion "name" =  yourName
getQuestion "weight" =  yourWeight    

runQuestion :: (Typeable a, Show a) => Question -> IO a
runQuestion (Simple message parser) = do
  putStrLn message
  ans <- getLine
  return $ parser ans

main = getLine >>= (runQuestion . getQuestion) >>= print
```

Type checking fails at here: `runQuestion :: (Typeable a, Show a) => Question -> IO a` with `No instance for (Typeable a0) arising from a use of ‘runQuestion’`.

If I remove the class constraints (`runQuestion :: Question -> IO a`) then I get `No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of ‘print`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type

```
Question -> IO a
```

means "a function that accepts a `Question` and returns an `IO a` *for whatever `a` the caller wants*". This is obviously wrong; some questions have an `Int` answer and some have a `String` answer, but no question has an answer that can on demand be `Int`, `String`, or whatever else we may want.

If all you need from the answer is the ability to show itself, just return a shown answer as an `IO String`.

```
type Message = String

data Question = Simple Message (String -> String)
  -- more constructors

yourName :: Question
yourName = Simple "Your name?" show

yourWeight :: Question
yourWeight = Simple "What is your weight?" (show . (read :: String -> Int))

getQuestion :: String -> Question
getQuestion "name" =  yourName
getQuestion "weight" =  yourWeight

runQuestion :: Question -> IO String
runQuestion (Simple message parser) = do
  putStrLn message
  ans <- getLine
  return $ parser ans

main = getLine >>= (runQuestion . getQuestion) >>= putStrLn
```

Otherwise you can move existentiality to the answer, which you need to encapsulate in a new GADT:

```
type Message = String

data Question where
  Simple :: Message -> (String -> Answer) → Question
  -- more constructors

data Answer where
  Easy ::  (Typeable a, Show a) => a -> Answer

instance Show Answer where
  show (Easy a) = show a

yourName :: Question
yourName = Simple "Your name?" Easy

yourWeight :: Question
yourWeight = Simple "What is your weight?" (Easy . (read :: String -> Int))

getQuestion :: String -> Question
getQuestion "name" =  yourName
getQuestion "weight" =  yourWeight

runQuestion :: Question -> IO Answer
runQuestion (Simple message parser) = do
  putStrLn message
  ans <- getLine
  return $ parser ans

main = getLine >>= (runQuestion . getQuestion) >>= print
```

but this is IMHO overkill.

Comment: Can we make Question an instance of Monad or Category? I like it to be composable :: `Question o -> (o -> Question o') -> Question o'` This way at design time I can ensure that the questions are sequenced and will be asked in a "rational" order.

Comment: While retaining the ability to `getQuestion :: String -> Question` as the first question perhaps.

Comment: The original `Question` has kind `*` (no type parameters). If you want it to be parameterized by the type of its answer, it's a whole different kettle of fish. You can have `String->Question` but `String->Question a` has the same problem you are having with `Question -> IO a`.

Comment: I think I'll lose one important feature by avoiding type parameters, I described it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147517/functions-of-gadts/39148323?noredirect=1#comment65641921_39148529

Answer (score 4):

The error you report is not the only error.

Let's put on the special spectacles which show the things usually kept invisible by "type inference".

Firstly, the data constructor:

```
Simple :: forall a. (Typeable a, Show a) =>
          Message -> (String -> a) -> Question
```

Effectively, a value of type `Question` looks like

```
Simple {a}{typeableDict4a}{showDict4a} message parser
```

where I've written the invisible things in braces. The constructor packs up a type and the two typeclass dictionaries that give the implementations for the members of `Typeable` and `Show`.

Now let's have the main program. I've renamed the type variable to make a point.

```
runQuestion :: forall b. (Typeable b, Show b) => Question -> IO b
```

The type to be given back is chosen by the caller of `runQuestion`, separately from whatever type is packed inside the argument of type `Question`. Now let's fill in the invisible components in the program itself.

```
runQuestion {b}{typeableDict4b}{showDict4b}
  (Simple {a}{typeableDict4a}{showDict4a} message parser) = do
                        -- so parser :: String -> a
      putStrLn message  -- ok, as message :: String
      ans <- getLine    -- ensures ans :: String
  return $ parser ans   -- has type IO a, not IO b
```

The `parser` computes a value of the type `a` packed up in the `Question`, which is totally separate from the type `b` passed directly to `runQuestion`. The program does not typecheck because there's a conflict between two types which can be made different by the program's caller.

Meanwhile, let's look at `print`

```
print :: forall c. Show c => c -> IO ()
```

When you write

```
main = getLine >>= (runQuestion . getQuestion) >>= print
```

you get

```
main = getLine >>=
  (runQuestion {b}{typeableDict4b}{showDict4b} . getQuestion) >>=
  print {b}{showDict4b}
```

and as the return type of `runQuestion {b}` is `IO b`, it must be the case that `print`'s `c` type is the same as `runQuestion`'s `b` type, but other than that, there is *nothing* to determine which type `b` is, or why it is an instance either of `Typeable` or `Show`. With the type annotation, the need for `Typeable` shows up first (in the `runQuestion` call); without, the need for `Show` in `print` causes the complaint.

The real problem, is that somehow, you seem to want `runQuestion` to deliver a thing in whatever type is hidden inside the question, as if you could somehow write a (dependently typed) program like

```
typeFrom :: Question -> *
typeFrom (Simple {a}{typeableDict4a}{showDict4a} message parser) = a

runQuestion :: (q :: Question) -> IO (typeFrom q)
```

That's a perfectly sensible thing to want, but it isn't Haskell: there's no way to name "the type packed up inside that argument". Everything which involves that type has to live in the scope of the case analysis or pattern match which exposes it. It's your attempt to do the `print` outside that scope that won't be allowed.

Comment: I thought that I will run into dependent types. I want to create a rational question/answer; meaning that the sequence of Questions should be type checked at compile time like: `Question a b { run :: a -> Input -> Either (b, Question b)}`. The last question in any chain ends with `Left finalResult`. The top Questions in a chain take no input perhaps `a = ()`. Questions probably form a Category. `b` the result depends on the result of the previous Question `a`. `a` and `b` are Typeable, Show and Read because I want to continue a chain by getting and feeding it `a` from somewhere (eg. Redis).

Comment: @homam can you show a specific example of a chain of questions? I'm having a hard time imagining how they might compose. To be specific, what question can you chain to either side of "What is your weight"?

Comment: @n.m. 
If `Simple :: lastResult -> Input -> Either result (result, Question result _)` then 
`yourName = Simple $ \ _ i -> Right (i, yourWeight)` 
`yourWieght = Simple $ \ name i -> let res = (name, read i :: Int) in Left res`. 
I can imagine that `yourName >>> yourWeight` is valid.

Comment: @homam so does `yourName >>> yourWeight` result include both name and weight? I don't think Haskell tyoe system can handle that. You need dependent types, open rows, or probably just plain old magic.

Comment: @n.m. yes, I want the result `yourName >>> yourWeight` to contain the result of both Questions. This way I ensure that `yourWeight` can only be asked after `yourName`. The whole thing is probably similar to creating a type safe state machine where transitions are type checked.