# How to write getters for existential types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Thanks to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143379/functions-to-polymorphic-data-types) I've defined a type like so:

```
data Chain = forall a. Integral a => Chain [[a]] [a] a a
```

I need to write a getter function for each field, or argument if you like. Here's my first attempt:

```
getSimplices (Chain simplices _ _ _) = simplices
```

But when I try to compile ghc gives the following error:

```
Chain.hs:10:40: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘t’ with actual type ‘[[a]]’
    because type variable ‘a’ would escape its scope
  This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
    a pattern with constructor:
      Chain :: forall a. Integral a => [[a]] -> [a] -> a -> a -> Chain,
    in an equation for ‘getSimplices’
    at Chain.hs:10:15-35
• In the expression: simplices
  In an equation for ‘getSimplices’:
      getSimplices (Chain simplices _ _ _) = simplices
• Relevant bindings include
    simplices :: [[a]] (bound at Chain.hs:10:21)
    getSimplices :: Chain -> t (bound at Chain.hs:10:1)
```

I fixed it like this:

```
getSimplices (Chain simplices _ _ _) = map (map fromIntegral) simplices
```

Even if some kind of ghc magic prevents this from being obscenely slow for a getter, I think fixing something this way is just atrocious. Is there a better way to define getters for types like this?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? The fact that you want to write a getter for an existentially quantified type suggests to me that you didn't really want an existential in the first place.

Comment: What I want is a single type that takes any integral data type for its fields

Comment: and you've got it, but what type should your getters produce? a consumer (caller) expects a certain Integral type, not "any Integral" type.

Comment: @EbenCowley [Don’t try to put constraints on datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770278/typeclass-constraints-on-data-declarations)

Comment: Hm alright I see the issue now

Comment: One thing you can do in a situation like this is use `RankNTypes` to write `withSimplices :: Chain -> (forall a. Integral a => [[a]] -> r) -> r; withSimplices (Chain ss _ _ _) k = k ss`. That is, within the function `k` you have access to the hidden type `a`, as long as 1. you use it in a fully polymorphic way (only depending on the fact that it’s `Integral`), and 2. the result type `r` doesn’t mention `a` (or else `a` would be used outside the scope of the `forall`). An existential isn’t what you want here, but this is a useful thing to know about when you do need an existential.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What type do you suppose `getSimplices` should have? The "obvious" choice is

```
getSimplices :: Integral a => Chain -> [[a]]
```

But this doesn't work with your implementation, because the caller  of `getSimplices` gets to choose the `a`, and there's no guarantee that the values stored in the `Chain` are of the same type that the caller wants, since you threw that information away. Consider:

```
let c = Chain [[1 :: Int]] [2] 3 4
in (getSimplices c) :: [[Integer]]
```

This is clearly allowed by your two type signatures which promise to work for any Integral type, but also clearly cannot work without some conversion: the `Int`s have to be turned into `Integer`s somehow.

As the comments say, this is rather unusual. It would be much simpler to add a type parameter to Chain, so that it tracks the type you used to create it, and constrains its output to that type as well:

```
data Chain a = Chain [[a]] [a] a a

getSimplices :: Chain a -> [[a]]
getSimplices (Chain xs _ _ _) = xs
```

Comment: it's common to expect, in other languages, an automatic conversion in such situations where the source and the target types are known (even if it weren't forgotten by `Chain`). But Haskell does no implicit conversions, ever. (IIRC).

Comment: Realistically doing this would be fine because this is a personal project and I know that `Chain` will never act on a non-integral type. But The point of asking this question was because I wanted to know how to do this with the extra safety of the `Integral` typeclass.

Comment: Due to the comment by Benjamin Hodgson I'm accepting this as the best solution

Answer (score 8):

The constructor of an existential type necessarily "forgets" about `a`:

```
Chain :: Integral a => [[a]] -> [[a]] -> a -> a -> Chain
```

Note how the resulting type no longer depends on `a`.

A consequence of this is that, when we pattern match on `Chain`, we can not make any assumption about what `a` is. After all we could have chosen anything when constructing. The only knowledge we have on `a` is that it must be an integral type. Hence, we can only access using the methods of the `Integral` type class.

The general rule is that, when we pattern match on `Chain`, we must return a value of a type which does *not* depend on `a`. A getter like

```
getter (Chain _ _ x _) = x
```

violate that rule. After all, what type would that have?

```
getter :: Chain -> ???
```

Surely not

```
getter :: Chain -> a
```

which would instead mean that we can extract any type we wish from `Chain`. This can not realistically work: we can't be free to choose what type to put in, and then be also free to choose what type to take out.

What we can do, however, is to exploit `Integral`:

```
getter :: Chain -> Integer
getter (Chain _ _ x _) = fromIntegral x
```

`Integer` does not depend on `a`, so it is OK.

Comment: nice. also, if OP's `getSimplices` were possible, what about `map getSimplices` then? each `Chain` in that argument list could be built from *anything* as long as it's an `Integral`, but `map` must produce values of the *same* type for all of them.